# Replace a call instruction with LLVM

Tags: replace, call, llvm, instructions

I’m a beginner in LLVM. And I want to replace all the call instructions in a program with “push next instruction address on stack, jump to callee function”. So does anyone know where can I implement this replacement? Write a pass and insert into the clang compiling chain? And how can I implement this replacement?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to push the next instruction on the stack? That is not a thing that makes sense in the LLVM world.

Comment: Actually, I want to do some protection on function call/return site. Sorry, it should be pushing "the next instruction address" on stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a new LLVM instrinsic. You will have to provide a target-specific definition for your intrinsic so that the compiler knows what machine code to generate. In your case you would provide a target-specific definition that implements push+jump.

Once you have your intrinsic you can create an LLVM pass that searches the LLVM IR for all `call` instructions that *aren't* to your intrinsic and replaces them with call instructions that *are* to your intrinsic.

Documentation on adding a new intrinsic function: http://llvm.org/docs/ExtendingLLVM.html

Tutorial on how to implement your own LLVM pass: http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html

Comment: Call instruction will push the instruction address after call into stack. So I want to replace call instruction with a push+jump instructions. I want to replace all the call instruction in ELF with push+jump instructions.

Comment: Thanks Mike for your answer. I tried to find some docs about LLVM intrinsic function, but it seems there are quite few examples online for a beginner. So far, I think I can do some search over IR on the call instruction and the instruction next to call (for ret). But still have no idea about how to make it into assembly. Can you provide more details about intrinsic or anything that may help. Thanks again

Comment: I finally implemented it on X86AsmPrinter layer. When printing the call instruction, I replace it with push+jmp. Thanks for your answer.